# Запрос с объединением

Tags: sql

Как заставить это работать?

```
 $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM prodtype_light WHERE pcode like '(UNION SELECT prodtype FROM prodvendor_light WHERE id = 1)%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM prodtype_light WHERE pcode like (SELECT prodtype+'%' FROM prodvendor_light WHERE id = 1)
```